# how to create thread for recieving data

Tags: c, linux, sockets, pthreads

```
tcp_socket()
{
      sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);

      if (sock == -1)
      {
          printf("Could not create socket\n");
      }
      puts("Socket created.......\n");

      server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.210.110.10");
      server.sin_family = AF_INET;
      server.sin_port = htons(PORT);

      //Connect to remote server
      con= connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server));

      if(con<0)
      {
          perror("connect failed. Error\n");
          return con;
      }

      puts("Connected\n");

      err = pthread_create(&tid, NULL,reciever_port,(int*)sock);
                  if (err != 0)
          printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
                  else
          printf("\n Thread created successfully\n");


      return 1;
  }


  void *reciever_port(int sockid)
  {
        unsigned char inbuf[MAX_REQUEST_LINES]="";

        while(1)
        {
            memset(inbuf, 0, sizeof(inbuf));
            rc=recv(sockid , inbuf , 1024 , 0);

            if(rc<0)
            {
                puts("waiting .........\n");
                exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                for(i=0;i<rc;i++)
                {
                    printf("%c",inbuf[i]);
                }   
            }
```

I have opened a client socket and call function `reciever_port` using `pthread_create`, in that `reciever_port` a while loop is continously receiving, if any data comes from server, but it is not printing anything, not working properly, whereas without thread it is working.

Am I missing something, or can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you pass `(int*)` to thread as argument, you should get `int*` as argument: `void *reciever_port(void* arg) { int sockid = * (int*) arg; ...`

Comment: @myaut Which is kind of evil, because `sizeof int` must not necessarily be <= `sizeof void *`

Comment: I think that's the thread start is the problem, make sure you pass parameters correctly to the thread function. In other words, receiving data is *not* the problem and you should leave that out for a moment. Another thing to look at in that context is the scope of `sock`: Above, it looks like it is global!

Comment: @dhke, Oh, I didn't notice that he doesn't take address of `sock`, but pass it directly.

Answer (score 2):

You have a pointer conversion problem:

```
  err = pthread_create(&tid, NULL,reciever_port,(int*)sock);
```

This converts the value of the `sock` integer into an `int *` pointer. There is no guarantee that this actually works on all platforms (that why there's usually an `intptr_t *`.

This line alone should also raise a compiler warning, because the type of `reciever_port` is

```
void *(*reciever_port)(int sockid);
```

while the type of the thread function is

```
void *(*start_routine)(void *);
```

I'm a little bit surprised that this actually compiles. You do have warnings enabled, do you?

In `reciever_port()` you implicitly convert that `void *`-disguised `int` back to an integer which is also not guaranteed to work.

To clean this up a little:

```
  int *thread_socket = calloc(1, sizeof(int));
  *thread_socket = sock;
  err = pthread_create(&tid, NULL,reciever_port,thread_socket);
  if (err != 0) { 
      free(thread_socket);
      [...]
  }
  [...]



  void *reciever_port(void *arg)
  {
       int socket = *(int *)arg;
       free(arg);
       [...]
```

Note that I'm not too happy with "*callee frees caller allocated memory*" in this code.

It is possible to avoid the alloc-free-dance when `sock` is a static variable that cannot go away, but this way you can actually create multiple threads. And if `sock` is a global variable, no need to bother passing it as an argument at all.

Your thread code might also need some additional work:

```
void *
reciever_port(int sockid)
{
     // MAX_REQUEST_LINES might be a misnomer, you don't read lines,
     // you read individual bytes/chars.
     unsigned char inbuf[MAX_REQUEST_LINES] = "";      

     while(1) {
         memset(inbuf, 0, sizeof(inbuf));
         // you really don't want 1024 as a magic number, here
         rc = recv(sockid, inbuf, sizeof(inbuf) ,0);

         if (rc < 0) {
             perror("Error receiving data: ");
             /* no need to kill everything when the thread exits */
             return NULL;
         } else {
             for(i = 0;i < rc; i++) {
                 putc(inbuf[i]);
             }
             fflush(stdout);
         }
    }
}
```

Note the explicit `fflush()` of the output stream. You might not get to see any output otherwise as `stdout` is typically line buffered and every write without a newline thus stays in memory until the buffer is full.

Comment: i implemented the code given above ,code is error free,but thread is not sensing data .  i am doing some mistake in thread plz guide

Comment: Are you *really* not getting any data or is is output just buffered, as you never issue an `fflush()` after doing `printf()` without a newline? Also: Any reason not to use `putc()`?

Comment: lol 'Note that I'm not too happy with "callee frees caller allocated memory" in this code. ' - since the pointer is getting copied to another stack, I don't see any way round it.  When writing multithreaded code, you will either have to accept that some dubious paradigms have to be dumped, or you will get into a real mess.   Cleaning up memory allocations before process termination also has to go.  Those who advocate such practices are those who have never actually written any complex multithreaded apps or, if they have, the apps have 'issues'.

Comment: @MartinJames That's why it's "not too happy", which translates to "this violates one of my general rules, so I'm trying to make extra sure that this works as it should" ;-)